# Access firestore value

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is firestore database structure. I'm trying to call these data in my flutter application. but I only get value upto document which is chatroom/9000. But i want collection of document 9000. How do i call it?

This is how i called query

```
await _firestore .collection('chatroom') .doc(UUID) .get() .then((value) { });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Future<dynamic>  getValues() async{ 

 var _chatroom =await _firestore .collection('chatroom').get((value)async{
     if(value !=null ){  
            for(var  index = 0 ;   index< value.documents.length ; index++ )
              var _chatitem = await _firestore .collection('chatroom') 
              .doc(value.value.documents[index].documentId) .get() .then((value) { 

                  // Do what you Want
               })
 
     }     
  });

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).